# UPDATE with INNER JOIN - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables one called `customer` and the other called `referrals` I need to add some numbers to two columns in table "referrals" but to know which ones, I need to refer the the table "customer" since its the one that has the group_id.

Here's an example of what I tried

```
UPDATE referrals AS r 
SET total_coins_received = r.total_coins_received + 2, unused_ref_coins = r.unused_ref_coins + 2
FROM customer AS c
WHERE c.group_id = '1' and c.subscription_state = 'active';
```

This ignored my WHERE state and updated all the fields even if it didn't match the "group_id"

How can I just reference that I need to just change the ones that apply to the conditions?

This is a fiddle with an example of what is happening: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/239

Comment: You are not using the `customer c` table. Is that your intention? Also, it is not associated with the `referrals r` table.  Is that your intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in the `WHERE` clause the condition that links the 2 tables:

```
WHERE c.cust_id = r.cust_id and c.group_id = '1' and c.subscription_state = 'active';
```

Without the condition `c.cust_id = r.cust_id` what you get is the cartesian product of `referrals` and the rows of `customer` that satisfy the conditions `c.group_id = '1' and c.subscription_state = 'active'` and this is why all the rows of `referrals` are updated.